# How to make oData case insensitive when query calls AsEnumerable?

Tags: linq, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Since .NET Core 3 we can no longer use GroupBy without calling AsEnumerable or ToList first.

The problem with calling AsEnumerable is that it makes the oData queries case sensitive. This filter with 'aaaa' does not find 'A' for instance:

https://localhost/myweb.api/api/mymethod?$filter=contains(Name,%20%27aaaa%27)

How can I make this case insensitive again?

this is not production code, just an example:

```
public IQueryable<Dto> GetDto(
{
    return (from a in _context.Names
            select new Dto
            {
                Name = a.Name
            })
            .AsEnumerable() // this is needed for the group by to work
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name })
            .Select(x => new Dto
            {
                Name = x.Key.Name
            })
            .AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: One option would be to do both the input and data tolower. In that case both is always the same and A will be found in aaaaa as it will be transformed to a.

Comment: Why you cannot call `GroupBy` without `AsEnumerable`? Do you prefer to load whole  table into the memory?

Comment: 1. If you are grouping by a single value, there is no reason to use anonymous objects, you can just do `x => x.Name` and then `Name = g.Key`. 2. Adding `AsQueryable` is normally not of any value. 3. If you just want distinct names, use `Distinct`: `(from a in _context.Names select a.Name).Distinct()`.

Comment: @NetMage like I said, this was just a example code. I am grouping by more than one argument.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, if I remove the AsEnumerable I get this error because of new breaking changes in .Net Core 3:  The LINQ expression  xxx could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."

Comment: @user441365, this "breaking" change prevents loading whole table into the memory. Looks like  your GroupBy is wrong.

Comment: @sdev95 the issue with this solution is that accentuated characters are not found. So if we search for 'mexico', 'méxico' will not appear

Answer (score 0):

You can try with same cases by making .tolower() or .toUpper() and apply where condition to filter the records:

```
var searchText = "A";
return (from a in _context.Names
            select new Dto
            {
                Name = a.Name
            })
        .Where(x=>x.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
            .AsEnumerable() 
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name })
            .Select(x => new Dto
            {
                Name = x.Key.Name
            })
            .AsQueryable();
```

Comment: yeah this doesn't work in my case becuase the real Dto contains multiple paramaters apart from "Name"

Comment: Your DTO is the select statement. What you really need is in where condition, whats the attributes u need to check with params from UI

Comment: I meant that my final dto will have many more properties, apart from Name. I can't use the where condition because the call can pass on a different parameter every time: $filter=contains(Plate,%20%27aaaa%27)  or $filter=contains(Glass,%20%27aaaa%27)